# Why can't the total angular momentum of a composite system be less than zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

After reading the following excerpt from Griffiths' "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics", in his discussion of the addition of angular momentum, I'm a bit confused as to why the total spin (and I suppose angular momentum) of two particles can't be less than zero.

[image]

In his example of a particle with spin 3/2 and another with spin 2, he declares that the total spin can range from 7/2 to 1/2. Why can't we find both of the particles with a -ve spin, so that they're parallel but "negatively". Is this because both of them being aligned but in the -ve direction, is just the same as both being aligned but in the +ve direction, and there's no clear way of distinguishing the two cases?

Comment: Does the North Pole point "up"? Why not the South Pole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnitude of a vector, $\left|\vec v\right|^2$, is always nonnegative.

For angular momenta in quantum mechanics we have the nontrivial result that the orbital angular momentum magnitude operator $\hat L{}^2$ has eigenvalues $L(L+1)\hbar^2$ for nonnegative integer $L$.  This result is buried in some hocus-pocus about how the Legendre polynomials turn into the spherical harmonics.

Spin is trickier because the four-state particle-antiparticle spinor arises from the Dirac equation, also in a nontrivial way.  (Dirac’s original paper is a good read.) At the level of Griffiths, spin angular momentum is an assumption to be clarified later.  However, you can probably rearrange the definition

$$
\hat S{}^2 = \hat S_x{}^2 + \hat S_y{}^2 + \hat S_z{}^2
$$

into a combination of $S_z$, $S_\pm$, and their commutators in a way that might convince you the eigenvalues of $S^2$ depend on the magnitude, but not the sign, of the eigenvalues of $S_z$ for which the ladder operators terminate.